# How do I get the number of leaves on my binary tree code?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have been getting 0 as the number of leaves on my binary tree. I do not see any problems with my code and would like some feedback. Thank You!:)

MAIN.cpp

```
int main()
{   
    BinaryTree <int> a;
    a.insertNode(13);
    a.insertNode(28);
    a.insertNode(8);
    a.insertNode(14);
    cout << a.numNodes() << endl;
    cout << a.numLeafNodes() << endl;
    cout << a.height() << endl;
    cout << a.getWidth() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Binary Tree Class header. This is my class that has the functions.

```
    template<class T>
class BinaryTree
    {
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        T value;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;
    };

    TreeNode *root;

    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    int countNodes(TreeNode *&nodePtr);
    void countLeaves(TreeNode* nodePtr);
    int getTreeHeight(TreeNode* nodePtr);
    int width(TreeNode* nodePtr);
public:
    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    void insertNode(T);
    int numNodes();
    int numLeafNodes();
    int height();
    int getWidth();
};
```

My Functions for getting the number of leaves. This is Where I am not sure the issue is.

```
template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::numLeafNodes()
{
    int leafCount = 0;
    countLeaves(root);
    return leafCount;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::countLeaves(TreeNode* nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {

        countLeaves(nodePtr->left);
        countLeaves(nodePtr->right);
        if (nodePtr->left == NULL && nodePtr->right == NULL)
        {
            int leafCount = 0;
            leafCount = leafCount + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
int BinaryTree<T>::numLeafNodes()
{
    int leafCount = 0;
```

This defines a variable named `leafCount`.

```
countLeaves(root);
```

This doesn't change the `leafCount` defined above.

```
return leafCount;
```

...so this returns `leafCount`, still holding the value `0`.

```
template <class T>
void BinaryTree<T>::countLeaves(TreeNode* nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {

        countLeaves(nodePtr->left);
        countLeaves(nodePtr->right);
        if (nodePtr->left == NULL && nodePtr->right == NULL)
        {
            int leafCount = 0;
```

This defines another, completely separate variable, that also happens to be named `leafCount`.

```
            leafCount = leafCount + 1;
```

This increments the variable defined immediately above.

```
        }
```

...and here this `leafCount` goes out of scope and is destroyed, without affecting anything outside its scope at all (and since there's no observable effect from this `leafCount` being created, incremented, or destroyed, chances are the the compiler will optimize all that out).

What you'd typically want would be something like returning a value that indicates the number of leaf nodes encountered. This would figure out whether the current node is a leaf node, and if so return 1. Otherwise, it would return the sum of the number of leaf nodes of its left and right sub-trees.

Comment: I changed some stuff but it still isn't working. I am not getting an error message it just stops half way through compiling and gives me a message saying exception unhandled.